# lift one side of a vehicle with ramps

Tags: jack, lifting

I've been looking at lots of ramp safety/proper use articles but they all seem focus on lifting the front of the vehicle.

On a vehicle with enough clearance to use a ramp at the rear tires, is there any reason you should not  lift one whole side of a vehicle by placing ramps at the front and rear tires and driving up?  Assume the tires on the other side would be blocked, parking break on, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure a general answer is possible. The stability of the vehicle on the ramps will depend upon the height of the ramps, and the height of the vehicle's center of gravity; these factors will determine how far the CoG moves towards the tire contact areas on the non-lifted side.

Answer (score 1):

You can lift one side safely as long as the center of gravity doesn't go past its tipping point, which will usually be the wheels on the non-lifted side. How far you can lift it depends on the vehicle, SUVs, smart cars and the like have a higher center of gravity than a sedan or sports car, so could be lifted less. You would need to find out the tip angle of the specific vehicle and do some calculations based on that.

Comment: In addition to this answer, I'd like to add (from personal experience driving in rough country) that most vehicles can withstand angles of 30 to 40 degrees.